# cleaning up noise words such as the, a, and or etc...

Tags: php, string, parsing, text, stop-words

I know this is a long shot but I'll ask it anyway.

I would like to run a filter over some text and I would like to delete the most occurring words in English such as "The", "a", "and", "or" etc...

Has this challenge been addressed somewhere so you can get a *pretty good* list of such words?

Comment: Are you asking about where to find such a list, or how to remove them from a string? In either case I would start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English) and [here](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: I was more on the side of finding such a list. Your link helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The official term for what you're looking for is "stop words". For the english language, I often use the stopwords.txt list from the Solr search engine:

https://code.google.com/p/solrmarc/source/browse/trunk/test/data/smoketest/solr/conf/stopwords.txt?r=1333

Comment: Very nice. Thanks to your starting link, I was able to find this which fits more to my bill. http://www.webconfs.com/stop-words.php

Comment: Glad I could help. It's always easier when you know what keywords to search for on Google.

Answer (score 0):

How about regex? Check out the "Words" section of this page, http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_regular_expressions_examples-136.html.  There are sample regex's including patterns that operate on words.

```
//Words: Whole word
//Match one of the words from the list
'\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use str_replace()

Example:

```
str_replace("and", "", $text);
```